# Manually changing package.appxmanifest instead of associating UWP App with Store

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-10, wns, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP Application, which needs to be build for two different project configurations i.e for two sets of Microsoft store Application identity and client id and client secret.

So for making two different builds all I do is change the identity tag in `package.appxmanifest` file. I need to test PushNotifications using WNS for these two project configurations.

The issue is when I manually set the identity tag in `package.appxmanifest`, the app doesnot receive a notification, but when I asssociate it with the store with the App in Windows store, the app starts getting push notification.

Is there any other file or certificate that needs to be removed for manually changing the identity tag, and making the App work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `identity` tag (inluce phone product id and package name) of the app must be the same as displayed in app store to enable push for this package. When you asssociate it with the app in store, Visual Studio did the copy paste for you.

To have difference build setting, just create a new app in dev center, asssociate your package with it before building to get new configuration.